# jquery select attribute of element not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use jquery "2.1.1"

It seems that select with attribute doesn't work for 'image' tag (execute in Chrome dev console)

```
> $("image")
< [<image preserveAspectRatio=​"none" href=​"img/​minus.png" x=​"5.5" y=​"3.5" width=​"16" height=​"16" fill=​"#E0E0E0" stroke=​"#DDDDDD" stroke-width=​"3" zIndex=​"1" transform=​"translate(-1,-1)​">​</image>​]

> $("image[href='img/minus.png']")
< []

> $('image[preserveAspectRatio="none"]')
< []

> $('img[href="img/minus.png"]')
< []

> $('img[src="img/minus.png"]')
< []
```

It does work for div tag:

```
> $('div[class="reportsTab tabStyle"]')
< [<div class=​"reportsTab tabStyle" id=​"reportsTab" data-bind=​"style:​ {height:​ tabHeight()​ + 'px'}​" style=​"height:​ 688.8px;​ display:​ block;​">​…​</div>​]
```

and for img tag:

```
> $('img[src="img/loading.gif"]')
< [<img src=​"img/​loading.gif">​, <img src=​"img/​loading.gif">​]
```

This code works OK

```
> $("image").attr("href")
< "img/minus.png"
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: `image` should be `img`. Are you sure the image exists in the DOM (and has those exact properties) at the point you are trying to select it? Check the console for errors.

Comment: as u can see in the first query - the image exist in the DOM with those exact properties

Answer (score 5):

try with `img`

```
$("img[href='img/minus.png']")
```

Comment: same result > $('img[href="img/minus.png"]')
< []

Comment: The HTML is part of the question - see the first query - <image preserveAspectRatio=​"none" href=​"img/​minus.png" x=​"5.5" y=​"3.5" width=​"16" height=​"16" fill=​"#E0E0E0" stroke=​"#DDDDDD" stroke-width=​"3" zIndex=​"1" transform=​"translate(-1,-1)​">​</image>

Comment: there is not tag <image> in html.html hava tag <img> for image

Comment: realy?! i search for tag image in html5 and does not found anything.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_new_tags.htm have new tag and there is not <image> tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76416/discussion-between-user1406269-and-ashkufaraz).

Answer (score 1):

It's because an image "tag" (element) is in fact `img` rather than `image`

Answer (score -1):

Image tag is like `<img>` hence you should write:

```
$("img[src='img/minus.png']")
```